# "Von hinten durch die Brust ins Auge"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

Dieser Ausdruck bezieht sich wohl ursprünglich auf den Weg eines Pfeils (oder einer Pistolenkugel) und beschreibt eine überaus umständliche und umwegige Vorgehensweise. Gibt es etwas adäquates auf englisch?

Comment: Nicht sehr vielversprechend :-( : https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=199570&idForum=1&lang=de&lp=ende

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ja, da war ich auch schon.

Comment: Ich glaube es gibt keine adequate Übersetzung, am Nächsten kommt wohl noch: _"to put the cart before the horse"_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ okay. Danke. (nicht "in front of" statt "before"?)

Comment: Ich bin kein _Native English Speaker_, wart mal ab ob da vielleicht noch eine gute Antwort von jemandem kommt, der Deutsch und Englisch gleichermassen gut beherrscht.

Comment: It wasn't my close vote. But the reasoning is clear. It certainly needs to have expertise, for both languages to provide a good translation. The pity is, that would apply for [SE English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com) rightous the same. That's why I upvoted your question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Walter explains the meaning of the phrase, it can also be explained to people who do not know German. No knowledge of German is needed to answer this question.

Comment: Auf Englisch kann ich da auch nichts beitragen. Auf Deutsch hätten wir noch 'erst dreimal mit der Kirche ums Dorf fahren' und [openthesaurus] (https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/edit/13920), die könnte man ja alle mal hinsichtlich englischer Übersetzungen abklappern.

Comment: Für **Umstandskrämer** liefert dict.cc _fussbudget (Am.), schlepper (Am.), fusspot (coll.)_.

Answer (score 2):

There are some expressions, mostly from the southern U.S. it seems, that have something to do with one's elbow:

> Going around your elbow to get to your ear

Source: [Expressions I didn’t realize were crazy until I moved away from the South](https://www.geek.com/news/expressions-i-didnt-realize-were-crazy-until-i-moved-away-from-the-south-1648062/)

> I had to go around my elbow to get to my thumb

Source: [“I had to go around my elbow to get to my thumb”—technology sucks](http://cassie.umwblogs.org/2012/02/16/i-had-to-go-around-my-elbow-to-get-to-my-thumb-technology-sucks/)

> Going around your ass to get to your elbow

Source: [20 Southern Sayings And The Meanings](https://www.theodysseyonline.com/20-southern-sayings-and-the-meanings)

There are probably more variations of it, but from what I can tell the elbow plays a role in most or all of them.

Comment: I've heard the elbow-thumb idiom  as well.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the (rather lame) translation

> he did something in a roundabout fashion

I have heard

> he did it butt-backwards (or, more hefty: ass-backwards)

which is somehow close to the German expression

Comment: There is no ass vor butt in the German expression.